# See How Many Bitcoins Existed

Tags: money-supply, reward-schedule, charts

Is there any way I can find out how many Bitcoins existed at a certain point in time?  Are there charts where I could, for example, see how many Bitcoins were in existence in 2011, so I could compare to the quantity existing today or something as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [This char](https://blockchain.info/charts/total-bitcoins?timespan=all&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=0&address=)t from blockchain.info is one. There are probably many more.